# iPhone動画再生の高速化手法

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg

iPhoneのネイティブプレイヤーで再生までの時間を高速化したいと思っています。
iPhoneでは
・mp4のプログレッシブダウンロード
・Http live streaming
の再生方法があると思いますが、再生開始するまでバッファリングなどの時間が必要です。

xvideosは動画再生開始ボタンを押すと素早く再生開始します。再生のスライドバーで再生位置を移動させても素早く開始します。

これはエンコードの方法が違うのでしょうか？ffmpegなどで変換できればと思っています。

xvideosはどうやって高速再生を実現しているか・またffmpegなどで実現する方法(もしくは別の方法)をご存知であればご教示お願いします。